# Intent Filter Not Working on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop, intentfilter

i have a problem with intent-filter on Android Lollipop (API 21)

i run my code on Android Nougat (API 25), my activity trigger the url. But the result is different when i try using android lollipop, the url open link on browser rather than asking to open with my app.

```
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="dev.syarq.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/register/verification"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Url given after click button from email : https://dev.syarq.com/register/verification?h=b3pLZTloYXJRdXg3TUFtLzNnTHdJUT09

here's a screenshot of two different result with the same code.

[image: Using Google Nexus 5 - API 21]

Click button from email -> open browser

[image: Using Google Nexus 5x - API 25]

Click button from email -> open chooser

Comment: Try installing one more browser app in the 5.0 and then you will see. Most likely you have added the browser app as app default in 5.0 device.

Comment: this browser the only browser i have in first time install

Comment: ahh, i see. there is an android icon on the left of tab icon (i using mozilla for android)